# Get golang coverage programmatically

Tags: go, code-coverage

The go -cover or -coverprofile is great when running go tests and can show nicely in html or plain text. But is there an api to access it programmatically or process the file?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [`axw/gocov`](https://github.com/axw/gocov), which:

- [will run test with a `-coverprofile` argument](https://github.com/axw/gocov/blob/bf5ca3ee473d38f90a53b218b09c6ae789736dec/gocov/test.go#L29-L38)
- parse the results ([`gocov/convert.go`](https://github.com/axw/gocov/blob/master/gocov/convert.go))

You can see a tool like [**GoCov GUI**](https://github.com/nsf/gocovgui) uses `gocov.Statement` in [`convert_statements(s []*gocov.Statement, offset int)`](https://github.com/nsf/gocovgui/blob/fd00420f3484838d076e00116a64b217616837a3/main.go#L78-L93) in order to build a small GUI:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c7865d70f68bcf9ba8a8d82cf40e75b254301be6/687474703a2f2f6e6f736d696c65666163652e72752f696d616765732f676f636f766775692e706e67]

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that we want to obtain test coverage percentage (as float64) on a project that we dynamically fetch from a git repo from somewhere, and store in the current folder under "_repos/src". The input would be the project in a typical "go get" format. We need to execute "go test -cover", with the properly GOPATH variable set, parse the output, and extract the actual percentage of the test coverage. With the current Go 1.9 testing tool, the code below achieves that.

```
// ParseFloatPercent turns string with number% into float.
func ParseFloatPercent(s string, bitSize int) (f float64, err error) {
    i := strings.Index(s, "%")
    if i < 0 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("ParseFloatPercent: percentage sign not found")
    }
    f, err = strconv.ParseFloat(s[:i], bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return f / 100, nil
}

// GetTestCoverage returns the tests code coverage as float
// we are assuming that project is a string
// in a standard "Go get" form, for example:
//     "github.com/apache/kafka"
// and, that you have cloned the repo into "_repos/src"
// of the current folder where your executable is running.
//
func GetTestCoverage(project string) (float64, error) {
    cmdArgs := append([]string{"test", "-cover"}, project)
    cmd := exec.Command("go", cmdArgs...)
    // get the file absolute path of our main executable
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return 0, err
    }
    // set the GOPATH for tests to work
    cmd.Env = os.Environ()
    cmd.Env = append(cmd.Env, "GOPATH="+dir+"/_repos/")

    var out []byte
    cmd.Stdin = nil
    out, err = cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return 0, err
    }

    r := bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(out))
    // first line from running "go test -cover" should be in a form
    // ok   <project>   6.554s  coverage: 64.9% of statements
    // split with /t and <space> characters
    line, _, err := r.ReadLine()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return 0, err
    }

    parts := strings.Split(string(line), " ")
    if len(parts) < 6 {
        return 0, errors.New("go test -cover do not report coverage correctly")
    }
    if parts[0] != "ok" {
        return 0, errors.New("tests do not pass")
    }
    f, err := ParseFloatPercent(parts[3], 64)
    if err != nil {
        // the percentage parsing problem
        return 0, err
    }

    return f, nil
}
```

Comment: Interesting. +1. My answer was written three years ago. No need for a downvote though.

Comment: No problem. I have made a small edit. I am still grateful for your contribution (with Go 1.9) to this old question.

Comment: I've stumbled on this for our repo marking subsystem. I use "test coverage" to check if the students are doing required test coverage. axw/gocov was a bit of overkill, and, it was not doing what I wanted - I just wanted the test coverage float, on repos that we pull dynamically.